# Hi, I am trying to create a trigger, which automatically calculates col1 + col2 and inserts the sum into col3 after the data insertion

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a trigger, which automatically calculates col1 + col2 and inserts the sum into col3 after the data insertion. For some reason there is an error,
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_tr
AFTER INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

test_one NUMBER(10);
test_two NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

SELECT random
INTO test_one
FROM test
WHERE id = id;

SELECT random2
INTO test_two
FROM test
WHERE id = id;

INSERT INTO test(test3) values ((test_one+test_two));


EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't select from the same table as trigger won't see it; table is mutating. Use pseudorecords.

```
SQL> create table test_one (random number, random2 number, test3 number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger test_tr
  2    before insert on test_one
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.test3 := :new.random + :new.random2;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test_One (random, random2)
  2  select 1, 2 from dual union all
  3  select 5, 3 from dual;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test_One;

    RANDOM    RANDOM2      TEST3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         5          3          8

SQL>
```

---

On the other hand, why bother with a trigger? Create a virtual column:

```
SQL> create table test_one
  2    (random     number,
  3     random2    number,
  4     test3      number as (random + random2) virtual
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_One (random, random2) values (3, 9);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_one;

    RANDOM    RANDOM2      TEST3
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          9         12

SQL>
```

---

Or, don't create *anything* and calculate `random + random2` when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my idea. Can you automatically insert  also the week number converted from DATE?

Comment: Sure; apply TO_CHAR function with appropriate format model to DATE datatype value, e.g. `to_char(sysdate, 'iw')`

Comment: create table test (
id NUMBER(4),
random DATE
)
ALTER TABLE test ADD test_date NUMBER(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_char(to_date(random,'yyyy/mm/dd'),'iw'));

TO_DATE('01/01/2030 09:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),

I am getting this error?

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: RANDOM already is DATE; don't TO_DATE it. It's just `ALTER TABLE test ADD test_date NUMBER (4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR (random, 'iw'));`

Comment: Mr Littlefoot you are the star. Thanks a lot. This SQL is killing me. Have couple of others things to do.

Comment: What is wrong here again?

ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN full_vac VARCHAR(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
(
CASE 
WHEN (random in 'car', 'vehicle' , 'train', 'plain') AND (random2 = 3) THEN 'Yes'
WHEN (random in 'hole') AND (random1 = 5) THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'NO'
END 
)

Comment: Remove COLUMN keyword; just ALTER TABLE TEST ADD FULL_VAC ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger, from Oracle 11gR1, you can use a virtual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test ADD test3 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (test1 + test2);
```

Alternatively, when you want to **display** the `test3` value then calculate it in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
SELECT test1, test2, test1 + test2 AS test3 FROM test;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d9c16c777bda406f65a5bbd3ba314fea)*

Comment: Virtual column was available in 11gr2 (tested), but [documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/wnsql.htm#SQLRF000) it should present in 11gr1.